# SwiftLint configuration rule

Tags: swift, indentation, swiftlint

I don't like the default formate of the indentation for switch cases in Xcode
and I prefer to make the formatting by 4 spaces 'tab' for switch cases so I read in documentation of [switch_case_alignment rule](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/switch_case_alignment.html) and found that I can change the configuration for switch_case_alignment rule so I added this code

```
switch_case_alignment:
  - indented_cases: true
```

to the .swiftlint.yaml file but it doesn't work with me is there any other solution

for more clarification here is the code I need it to be without warning from swiftlint

```
switch test{
    case first: break
    case sec: break
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? When you not indent switch cases, the rule doesn't get triggered? Btw you can change the default Xcode behaviour in Xcode Preferences > Text Editing > Indentation > Indent switch/case labels in: Swift.

Comment: I mean it stills give me warning for the formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration has a bad syntax, there should be no prefix dash (-) when configuring rules.

Your configuration should be

```
switch_case_alignment:  
  indented_cases: true
```